# Unable to locate a file while running an executable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have created a simple JAVA project, which accesses an internal file called **config.json** and writes content to a file **output.txt**.
As I did not want to send arguments to the main class, I added my **config.json** to the resource folder.

I am able to run the application in Eclipse without any issue.
Both `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resource/config.json")` and `this.getClass().getResource("/resource/config.json")` are able to locate the file from the path `C:/Users/divya_raibagkar/workspace/TestProject/**bin**/resource/config.json`
But when I export it to JAR and try to execute from command prompt using `java -jar D:/Test.jar`, I get the following error:

```
Returned file path: resource/config.json
Loading JSON config file:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource\config.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Java Project Structure:
[image: Java Project Structure]

Any lead to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.
Thank you.